# How do I integrate Fedex into my asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fedex

How do I integrate Fedex into my asp.net application. Is there any dll available from Fedex. I googled it but couldn't find any dll. Also I am completely new at integrating payment gateway, shipping etc. What are the initial steps I should take?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What do you mean by "Integrate" ? Shipping calculation?

Comment: @Vince Panuccio : Yes shipping calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fedex's Development Gateway](http://fedex.com/us/developer/) should have all the resources you need. If you are seriously trying to create a payment gateway though, its not exactly beginner's stuff. I'd suggest you do some serious googling on how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by `create`? I am not trying to create payment gateway I am trying to understand how to use payment gateway.

Comment: FedEx, from what I understand is not a payment gateway. It is a shipping tool. What are you trying to use exactly?

Comment: Once you go to the Fedex Development Gateway, you need to create an account to get into the Technical Resources that have a lot of documentation and examples to ues. I use the web services to tie into our WinForms app, for address validation and shipment cost rating. It is a big Web Services API that takes some time to understand. But once you understand it, there is a lot you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If it's shipping calculations your after, try this.

http://code.google.com/p/aspnet-dotnet-ups-usps-fedex-shippping-calculator/